# How do Cogs and belts work? / Cogs and belts in an ICAS exam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation, electrical-engineering

[image]

---

Does the left red wheel turn in the same direction as the leftmost orange wheel?If so P and S go up? If not, Q and S go up?

My reasoning:

If so

1. Leftmost orange cc
2. Left red cc (by assumption)
3. Leftleast orange clock --> P goes up
4. Gray cc
5. Right least orange clock
6. Right most orange clock (similar to assumption)
7. Right red cc --> s goes up

If not

1. Leftmost orange cc
2. Left red clock
3. Leftleast orange cc --> Q goes up
4. Gray clock
5. Right least orange cc
6. Right most orange clock (similar to assumption)
7. Right red cc --> s goes up

Comment: Think of this very, very, very intuitively. What happens if you combine two cylinders with a rubber band? Or think of you bike chain - when you push the pedals one way, which way dies the wheel then go, which is connected by a teeth chain?

Comment: When two gears mesh they have to turn in opposite directions (just picture them turning, there's only one way the teeth actually work).  A belt makes them rotate at the same speed, and in the same direction.  It's fairly intuitive, you just have to think about how those parts would work in real life.

Comment: @JMac do you disagree with steeven? Thanks ^-^

Comment: @Steeven do you disagree with jmac? Thanks ^-^

Comment: @BCLC Does it seem like we disagree with each other?

Comment: @BCLC Do *you* disagree with us? As you might have noticed by now, we are trying to make you understand so you can figure it out yourself - not just give you the answer. What are your thinking and answers to my follow-up questions for example?

Comment: @Steeven (edited a comment from before) oh that's strange. I thought your comment said wheel goes other way. I didn't notice your comment was a question and not declarative. will have to check again later. Thanks

Comment: @Steeven ok so for bike chains, the wheels turn in the same direction. therefore it's P and S. I guess? I'm gonna post this as answer and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my general strategy for solving these types of problems -- start at the gear with the known rotation, and work out the rotation of the other gears from there. Arrows help.

[image]

As per your discussion on bikes, the following should clear it up:

[image]

The bike case is represented by the system on the right. Consider a simple design for a bike where the wheels turn in the same direction as the cogs. Since both wheels turn the same way, both cogs must also turn the same way -- otherwise, you'd end up with a bit of a problem :)

Comment: thanks user256872! any idea why my comments about the bike chains and which direction were deleted? the main issue i'm wondering here is if bike chain wheels turn in the same direction. i think if you included this in your answer, then it would be complete

Comment: @BCLC No clue why it was removed -- I did not see it in the first place. I updated my post. Does it answer your question?

Comment: ok need 2 hrs to wait to award bounty. thanks!

Comment: No worries -- thank you :)